# Loading slow: LESS - Bootstrap variables cause waiting time

Tags: performance, twitter-bootstrap, less, page-load-time

I have the following setup: 
Joomla! 3.2.2, Bootstrap 3.1 with LESS.
I tested my page loading time and got a bad result, mainly because of LESS.

The loading time overall was 7.96s. The waiting for bootstrap/LESS variables was 5.3s!!!

It loads all the bootstrap variables:

```
template.less ~.com/templates/c~/less/  9.1 kB  
  bootstrap.less    1.3 kB  
  variables.less    19.6 kB   
  mixins.less   24.2 kB   
  normalize.less    7.4 kB  
  print.less    1.9 kB  
  scaffolding.less    2.1 kB  
  type.less   5.3 kB  
  code.less   1.3 kB  
  grid.less   2. kB  
  tables.less   4.5 kB  
  forms.less    9.2 kB  
  buttons.less    3.7 kB  
  component-animations.less   786 B   
  glyphicons.less   14.8 kB   
  dropdowns.less    4. kB  
  button-groups.less    5.1 kB  
  input-groups.less   3.5 kB  
  navs.less   5.1 kB  
  navbar.less   13.8 kB   
  breadcrumbs.less    817 B   
  pagination.less   2.1 kB  
  pager.less    1.1 kB  
  labels.less   1.3 kB 
  badges.less   1.3 kB  
  jumbotron.less    1.2 kB  
  thumbnails.less   1. kB  
  alerts.less   1.7 kB  
  progress-bars.less    1.8 kB  
  media.less    1.1 kB  
  list-group.less   2.1 kB  
  panels.less   4.2 kB  
  wells.less    812 B   
  close.less    96 B   
  modals.less   3.3 kB  
  tooltip.less    2.8 kB  
  popovers.less   3.5 kB  
  carousel.less   4.8 kB  
  utilities.less    1. kB  
  responsive-utilities.less   5. kB
```

That's fine by me. I won't even comment out many to perform better, becasue I need most of them.

**But is there a way to raise the speed of page load in any kind of way?**

It's basically not the rendering of the styles but the waiting time for server actions for loading the variables that let it take long. [pingdom.com](http://tools.pingdom.com): "The web browser is waiting for data from the server".

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance, you want to compile the less files and upload the resulting CSS to the server. Compiling on the server is convenient for development but not such a great idea in production.

Comment: Thanks for this hint so far. Can you recommend a tool for it, or is it just about reading out the browser source code after page load?

Comment: Personally, I use http://incident57.com/codekit/ which is commercial . I've also used http://incident57.com/less/ which is free. If you Google LESS compilers you'll find lots of other options as well. Good luck!

Comment: Thank You, David! Your response is really helpful.

Comment: To give you an idea of what you can expect, I'm running similar LESS builds. If I compile and minify the CSS, I end up with a single 40-50KB CSS file. The size will be reasonable plus you don't have multiple HTTP requests for all the less files or need to wait for less.js to compile every time a page loads.